# Krull dimension $\leq$ transcendental degree

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-verification

I am trying to solve Exercise 11.32 from the [online notes](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/commalg-2013/main.pdf) of Gathmann on Commutative Algebra:

> Let $K$ be a field and $B$ a not necessarily finitely generated $K$-algebra that is a domain. Show that the transcendental degree of $Frac(B)$ over $K$ is greater than or equal to the Krull dimension of $B$ and give an example where the inequality is strict.

How to show this?

This my idea for an example of strict inequality. Let $K$ be algebraically closed and $B=K[xy,xy^2,xy^3,...]$. It's field of fractions is $K(x,y)$ (inverting $xy$ gives us $y$ and inverting $y$ gives us $x$) and hence the transcendence degree is $2$.

I claim that the Krull dimension is $1$, $B/xy=K$ and $B/xy^k$ has (only) nilpotents for $k>1$ and therefore I believe the maximal ideals are of the form $xy-a$ for $a\in K$. Is this right?

Comment: There is an issue with the chain of subfields you describe: if $P_1\subset P_2\subset B$ are primes, we generally won't have $\mathrm{Frac}(B/P_1)\supset\mathrm{Frac}(B/P_2)$.

Comment: You are right, I have made a new try.

Comment: Any one likes to provide a correct answer or a hint?

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that $B/(xy) \simeq K$.

Comment: Could you explain this? What are the prime ideals of $B$?

Comment: I care about the prime ideals because I want to know the krull dimension of $B$. The reason for this is that I was expecting it to be strictly less than $2$, which is the transcendence degree of $frac(B)$. If that is the case I would have a nice example of a subring of a finitely generated $k-algebra$ for which krull dimension and transcendence degree do not agree. Part 1 of my question has apparently already been answered at mo.